# Make an exact copy of uiview which is desired to be never used itself except of for making exact copy instances of it

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have a view in storyboard in scene laying out of view hierarchy just like `firstResponder` and exit objects just like an object and this view, lets call it `supplementaryView`, wired to multiple views via `IBOutlet`.

The views it's wired to and `supplementaryView` is of my custom classes. The views having it as `IBOutlet` are designed to receive this view via setter and then make a copy and add to self as subview and some property.

So `supplementaryView` is kind of like fully designed instance of `supplementaryView` which is never to be used for anything except copying. Also this `supplementaryView` is a custom class which has `initWithFrame` and `initWithCoder` overriden, has no xib and fully constructed from code with `NSLayoutConstraints`.

What is my best option to make a copy of this `supplementaryView` at runtime?

Should I implement `NSCopying` and copy `IBInspectable` and other custom properties along with properties of `UIView` myself?

Or is it better to do some walking over properties of class at runtime with `class_copyPropertyList`?

Or is there some better options?

Comment: tl;dr; please brief in less words and do format the question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implement `NSCopying` on a `UIView` you will get an exception, views are not meant to be copied, however there is a trick that you can do to make this happen, you can use `NSKeyedArchiver` to archive the `UIView` object and then unarchive it, essentially "copying" the view. Something like:

```
id viewCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:viewToCopy]];
```

Comment: can you tell a bit about how this archiving and unarchiving will change `UIView`?

Comment: @IgorMuzyka It won't change UIView, but it will archive (serialize) and object and deserialize it, essentially giving you a copy of the view.